# UV unwrapping on textured mesh: Textures not visible after unwrapping

Tags: mesh, uv

I loaded a textured mesh by loading the obj file and assigning  *color attribute* to  *base color* option under *material properties*, however, I noticed that when I performed UV unwrapping, regardless of the type of projection I used (e.g., sphere, cylinder, or smart UV project), my textures were not visible in the unwrapped version when viewed with UV editor.

I am wondering if there is a solution to make my red textures, which are visible on the mesh, also appear on the unwrapped version.

[image]

Comment: On the top of the UV Editor, select the image?

Comment: @moonboots, thanks for the reply. The mesh I have is textured (As you can see the read color on the mesh) already, and I don't have a separate texture image file that I can load in the UV editor. The only texture information I have is in the mesh already.

Comment: Oh ok you've used vertex paint? in that case you can't see any image, but if you need an image you can probably bake the vertex paint

Comment: It sounds as if you would have to bake the vertex-colors into an image, if you want UV-mapping to read from it (e.g. plug the color attribute straight into a material output, and bake the 'Emit' into an active image-node)?